# Cannot read configuration file because it exceeds the maximum file size - Debug

Tags: asp.net, debugging, web-config

First of all, I already knew the solution to increase max web.config file size using regedit. It work if I open my project from IIS. However, when I try to debug my project using Visual Studio, it didn't work at all.

So, are there any way I can debug my project with large web.config file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can all you have to do is just run your Visual Studio in Admin Mode and then create  virtual directory using VS directly.

You run Visual Studio. This will work.